# Are reputation points counted in total or per site?

Tags: discussion, support, reputation

I'm kinda confused, because I'm new enough that I can't upvote but I know that I've had at least 15 notifications about reputation points... Where do I find my reputation count anyway?

And as a side question, how long have the users with 200 reputation points been here? There's a bunch of things that don't work unless you have that much, including the flair badges and that little graph on your user profile.

*Edit:* I realize there is a similar-sounding question, but that question/answer thread never explained that a user has a different reputation score for each stack, unlike the answers found here. (Thanks)

Answer (score 2):

There is a way to see your reputation across the entire exchange, but the reputation you see in the top bar and in your signature icon are relative to the current exchange.

As for reputation, each exchange can customize privileges but for the most part they are the same per site. You can find them at /help/privileges on any exchange, or by clicking the privileges link in your profile.

I am not sure what the average time of each account, but on Stack Overflow 207,000 people have over 200 reputation.

It isn't uncommon for users to take a while to get reputation, but that isn't the only reason to use the exchange. It is best used when you get stuck on a problem. If you cannot find a solution, or piece together a set of solutions to solve your problem, you can ask a question with only 1 reputation point.

Answer (score 1):

> Are reputation points counted in total or per site?

Both (total rep points can be seen in network-wide flair). But your priveleges on one site depend on your reputation there.

> Where do I find my reputation count anyway?

On any site, you can find your rep:

- Under any of your posts

  > [image]
- In the black top bar
- In your profile:

  > [image]

> And as a side question, how long have the users with 200 reputation points been here?

From one day :) It is possible to earn up to 200 reps from upvotes and approved suggested edits. Bounties, accepts, assoc bonus are exempt from those 200 reps, called "daily reputation limit" or simply "rep cap" (more info: [How does "Reputation" work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work)).

> There's a bunch of things that don't work unless you have that much, including the flair badges and that little graph on your user profile.

Accounts are included in your [*network* graph](https://stackexchange.com/users/5266710/vector-lightning?tab=reputation) and [*network* flair](https://stackexchange.com/users/5266710/vector-lightning?tab=flair) after after reaching 200 reps.

But still, your [site-only flair](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/274985/vector-lightning/flair) (this one is for this site - Meta Stack Exchange), and [rep graph](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/274985/vector-lightning?tab=reputation&sort=graph) (another kind of graph however) are available for you at any rep.